Why the product name cannot be deleted
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'price')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'price')
A Type Error appears on the screen.
import React, { useEffect ,useState} from 'react';
import PayMockup from '../PayMockup';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function TotalPayMent(){
    const total=PayMockup;
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
    const {userid} =useParams()
    console.log("userid", userid);

    console.log("totalpay", total.order.products[0].price);

    useEffect(()=>{
     const totalpay = total.order.products.find((product) =>product.id == userid); 
     console.log("totalpay", totalpay);
        setProduct(totalpay)
    },[userid])

    return(
        <div className='total-payment'>
            <p>최종 결제금액</p>
            <div className='totalpay' key={product.id}>
                <p className='price-title'>상품가격</p>
                <p className="product-price">{product.price}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


The Error can also be handled as below:

With Optional Chaining:
<p className="product-price">{product?.price}</p>


With Conditional Rendering:
<p className="product-price">{product && product.price}</p>




I implemented it using conditional rendering and it was implemented well on the screen.
import React, { useEffect ,useState} from 'react';
import "../TotalPayMent/TotalPayMent.css"
import PayMockup from '../PayMockup';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';



export default function TotalPayMent(){
    const total=PayMockup;
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
    const {userid} =useParams()
    console.log("userid", userid);

    console.log("totalpay", total.order.products[0].price);

    useEffect(()=>{
     const totalpay = total.order.products.find((product) =>product.id == userid); 
     console.log("totalpay", totalpay);
        setProduct(totalpay)
    },[userid])

    return(
        <div className='total-payment'>
        <p className='total-title'>최종 결제금액</p>
        {product && ( 
          <div className='totalpay' key={product.id}>
            <p className='price-title'>상품가격</p>
            <p className="product-price">{product.price}원</p>
            <p className='product-coupone'>쿠폰할인</p>
            <p className='product-coupone'>{total.order.cupon}원</p>
            <p className=' product-point'>포인트 할인</p>
            <p className='product-point'>{total.order.point}원</p>
            <p className='delivery-peice'>배송비</p>
            <p className='delivery-peice'>{product.delivery}원</p>
            <div className='total'>
            <p className='total-payment'>총 결제금액</p>
            <p className='total-payment'>{product.totalprice}원</p>
        </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
}

